# Cannot get to msysgit bash prompt

Tags: git, msysgit

I did see a similar question when searching but it did not have an answer.

I am following a tutorial on RoR and Git.  I followed all of the instructions carefully and downloaded msysgit 1.8.0 for my laptop running Windows 7.

However, when I run Git Bash, all I get is a flashing cursor... I have waited up to 10 minutes and still all I get is a flashing cursor, it never prompts and will not allow me to input type.  I have uninstalled/reinstalled Git several times and tried some later versions, but still I can not get Git Bash to work.

Does anybody have any ideas of how I can get Git to work?  This is my first time posting here and I am fairly new to programming etc so I hope I have given all information needed.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is "git bash"? Are you running msys.bat/git-cmd.bat?

Comment: @DaveNewton: git bash is a shortcut that will be created in the start menu. It points to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"`

Comment: Does `git-cmd` work at least? Do you have a similar issue with GitHub for Windows (which has powershell session)?

Comment: No, when I open the cmd folder and try to manually run the git.exe wrapper, the program flashes up and automatically closes.  I installed Git on an older/slower Windows 7 laptop, and it ran perfectly fine... I do not know why it will not run on this machine.

Comment: I am able to run Git Shell after downloading GitHub.  Will Git Shell allow me to do the same things as Git / Git Bash??

Comment: I believe the Github "Git Shell" is not a Bash, but a PowerShell. It does offer the same commands, though.

Comment: This will be tough to debug on SO. Just one random idea -- do you have cygwin installed? Is it in your system PATH? Cygwin and MSYS do not get along well. To debug further, do you get any output from git.exe in the Git/cmd directory? Can you run bin/git.exe?

Comment: I would recomend to install GitExtensions, which installs msysgit also. It is painless.